Must Hardy-Littlewood constants of unrelated discriminants be unequal?
Let $f_i$ denote quadratic functions of $x$, and $D_i$ their discriminants. Let $H$ denote Hardy--Littlewood constant of a specified discriminant. Then I understand that $H(D_1)=H(D_2)$ provided that:

the $f_i$ are either both reducible, in which case $H(D_i)=0$, or both irreducible
$D_1:D_2$ is the ratio of squares
$D_1$ and $D_2$ are divisible by the same odd primes

The conjunction of those three conditions is sufficient. Is it necessary? That is, may "provided that" be replaced by "iff"? (If "No", then what if the question is restricted to the cases where the $f_i$ are irreducible?) Or is there some subtlety that I've missed?
I'm particularly interested in $H(-8)$ and $H(-24)$. (One may take $x^2+2$ and $x^2+6$, or $2x^2+1$ and $2x^2+3$, for the $f_i$.)
I see no proof that they are equal. They defy my numerical attempts to demonstrate a difference between them.
What have I tried? Evaluating the respective H-L products, and taking terms as far as $p=270004039$ gives
$H(-8)\approx 0.3565311$ and
$H(-24)\approx 0.3565196$. (Beyond $2^{28}$, GAP, the numerical methods package I'm using, starts using bignum arithmetic, and the method to go through primes gets much slower).
Another way is to count primes $x^2+2$ and $x^2+6$. I make the counts for $0\leqslant x<10^9$ to be 18127693 & 18131000. My run output the totals for every $10^6$, and these showed that $x^2+2$ and $x^2+6$ both held the lead for so long that the run didn't even convincingly show which count retains the lead as $x\to\infty$.

Theory
A helpful equation is to be found in [Cohen]. It is a little more general than I need, but for the present purposes, it is enough to take
the Hardy--Littlewood constant of the quadratic function $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ as
\begin{align}
H(f) &= c_2 \prod_{\textrm{prime } m>2} \bigg[1 - \frac{(D\backslash m)}{m-1} \bigg]
\label{cohen2}
\end{align}
where $D=b^2-4ac$. $c_2$ depends on $f$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
c_2 &=
 \begin{cases}
  1/2, & a+b \textrm{ is odd}\\
  1, & a+b \textrm{ is even, $c$ is odd}\\
  0, & a+b \textrm{ and $c$ are even}
 \end{cases}
\end{align*}
The conditional use of $1/2$ and 1 is a subtlety that I had indeed missed when writing the question. It matters when comparing the prime densities of polynomials with different values for $a$ and/or $b$. However, where the polynomials differ only in their constant term, we may ignore $c_2$ and concentrate on the product, which depends on $f$ only through $D$. Call it $P(D)$.
So the question to be answered is to prove or refute the null hypothesis that $P(-24)=P(-8)$. For this, we don't need $P(-24)$ and $P(-8)$ separately, only their ratio $P(-8)/P(-24)$.
Use $\otimes$ to denote the combination of product-series, where the series' terms are collectively sorted in increasing order of $p$ and then multiplied in that order, and $S\oslash\prod_{p} f(p)$ to denote $S\otimes\prod_{p}\frac1{f(p)}$.
Then, where the term $1-\frac12=\frac12$ comes from $p=3$,
\begin{align*}
P(-8) &= \frac12 \prod_{p=1, 11, 17, 19\mod 24}\bigg[\frac{p-2}{p-1}\bigg] \otimes \prod_{p=5, 7, 13, 23\mod 24}\bigg[\frac{p}{p-1}\bigg] \\
P(-24) &= \prod_{p=1, 5, 7, 11\mod 24}\bigg[\frac{p-2}{p-1}\bigg] \otimes \prod_{p=13, 17, 19, 23\mod 24}\bigg[\frac{p}{p-1}\bigg] \\
\implies \frac{P(-8)}{P(-24)} &= \frac12
\prod_{p=17, 19\mod 24}\bigg[\frac{p-2}{p-1}\bigg] \otimes \prod_{p=5, 7\mod 24}\bigg[\frac{p}{p-1}\bigg] \oslash
\prod_{p=5, 7\mod 24}\bigg[\frac{p-2}{p-1}\bigg] \oslash \prod_{p=17, 19\mod 24}\bigg[\frac{p}{p-1}\bigg]\\
&= \frac12 \prod_{p=5, 7\mod 24}\bigg[\frac{p}{p-2}\bigg] \otimes
\prod_{p=17, 19\mod 24}\bigg[\frac{p-2}{p}\bigg]\\
&= \frac12 \frac53\frac75\frac{15}{17}\frac{17}{19}\frac{29}{27}\frac{31}{29}\frac{39}{41}\frac{41}{43}\frac{53}{
51}\frac{65}{67}\frac{79}{77}\frac{87}{89}\frac{101}{99}\frac{103}{101}\frac{111}{113}\dots
\end{align*}
This means that, compared to a simpler approach of evaluating the series for $P(-8)$ and $P(-24)$ separately, the above indicates that only half as many numbers need be tested for primality.
Numerical estimates based on the above theory
Denote by $y(N)$ the estimate of $P(-8)/P(-24)$ calculated by taking the terms for $p\leqslant N$.
I graph some of the partial products $y(N)$, for $N$ ranging up to $4560000019$.
$P(-8)/P(-24)$ estimates" />
One limitation of my numerical calculation is that all the multiplications and divisions were done using GAP's floating-point numbers, which are only the bog-standard IEEE 64-bit ones. The significand/mantissa is 53 bits (the leading 1-bit being implicit), so the precision is 1 part in $2^{52}$, the LSB being $l=2^{-52}$. My run reached $N>45\cdot10^8>2^{32}$. $p/(p-2)\approx1+2^{-31}$ giving only $52-31=21$ effective bits of precision in the mantissa.
The product to $N$ had $t\approx \pi(N)/2\approx 106\cdot10^6$ terms; nearly $2^{27}$. If each has an error from a distribution with mean 0 and standard deviation $l/2$, the standard deviation of their sum is about $\sqrt{t}l/2\approx 5000l$. So I have lost about 12 bits of precision, leaving me only about $21-12=9$ bits.
For what it was worth, I repeated the exercise but inverting all the fractions, to calculate $P(-24)/P(-8)$.
It seems pretty clear that by $N\approx 36\cdot10^8$, the variation of $y(N)$ with $N$ is much smaller than $y(N)-1$, and the figures suggest a limit $P(-8)/P(-24)\approx 1.00003$.
Numerical estimates based on prime-races
The pertinent prime races are $x^2+2$ v $x^2+6$ and $2x^2+1$ v $2x^2+3$. In the first race, $x$ must be odd* and the polynomials are in effect $4y^2+4y+3$ and $4y^2+4y+7$ where $x=2y+1$, so for a fair comparison between the two races, choose some $X$, and run the $x^2+2$ v $x^2+6$ race for $x\leqslant2X+1$, and the $2x^2+1$ v $2x^2+3$ race for $x\leqslant X$.
I took $X=600000000$.
Of the odd integers $0\leqslant x\leqslant 1200000001$, $x^2+2$ is prime for 21554259 of them, and $x^2+6$, for 21556771.
Of the integers $0\leqslant x<600000000$, $2x^2+1$ is prime for 21941602 of them, and $2x^2+3$, for 21936272.
Denote the count of primes found of form $f$ by $C(f)$. I find that, with the above results,
\begin{align*}
P(-8)/P(-24) \approx C(x^2+2)/C(x^2+6)=21554259/21556771 &=0.9998835\\
P(-8)/P(-24) \approx C(2x^2+1)/C(2x^2+3)=21941602/21936272 &= 1.0002430.
\end{align*}
These are in the ratio $\approx 1.00036:1$,
showing that the estimates of $P(-8)/P(-24)$ produced by counting primes have, at this stage, an inaccuracy so large that it swamps the difference between $P(-8)/P(-24)$ and 1, the latter difference estimated to be $\approx 1.00003$.
My investigation was prompted by prime-races. However, the above results show that calculating partial products using Cohen's equation yields more accurate results than running the prime-races themselves.
References
[Cohen] Henri Cohen. High-precision computation of Hardy--Littlewood constants. 1998.
*except for $0^2+2=2$
